# 64 bit support for IBM MQ

Tags: c#, dll, 64-bit, ibm-mq

I have inherited some legacy code, it is basically a wrapper for IBM MQ.  It has a reference to IBM.XMS.dll 2.0.50727.  Does this DLL support 64 bit OS like WIN2K16?

I've updated the build properties to Any CPU but I am not sure if this DLL can be run in 32 and 64 environments.

IBM MQ Clients are up to version 9 now, should I just download the latest version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> IBM MQ Clients are up to version 9 now, should I just download the
>   latest version?

Yes and if you install the IBM MQ Client V9 on a 64-bit PC then the 64-bit versions of the DLLs will be installed too.

i.e.

- the 32-bit DLL will be in the {MQ_install_dir}\bin\ directory
- the 64-bit DLL will be in the {MQ_install_dir}\bin64\ directory